# Unit Testing with SenTestingKit: Check if On?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing

I have some `NSLog` calls that I do to keep myself from flying blind in my unit tests. I can see them in the Build Results window, which works out nicely. Now I'd like to NOT run these except in the unit testing context (for instance, the target?). Is there a standard way to know if I'm inside a Unit Test or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a standard way, but you could define a preprocessor value in your test target and write your own log function to have the preprocessor strip the logging if that value is not defined.

Comment: Yes, that could work. How do you set up the value in the test target, and how do you retrieve it at preprocessing time?

Comment: Look in the build setting for the test target for the "Preprocessor Macros" setting (GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS).  Set something like TEST_TARGET here.  In your code you can use `#ifdef TEST_TARGET`